# How to download all attachments from sent mail in Opera Mai to certain directoryl?

Tags: opera, email-client, attachments

How to download all attachments from sent mail in Opera Mail to certain directory let's say `C:\Opera`? Tried many things for few hours. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click selected email, select fetch complete message, and "Attachments" will appear at mail header.